# Нужен ли конструктор, если я использую Getter() and Setter()?

Tags: java, конструктор, getter, setter

Если при создания сущности, его поля я инициализирую с помощью геттеров и сеттеров, нужен ли мне в таком случае конструктор?

```java
package Family;

public class Dad {


    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String keyPhrase;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = "Big Dad";
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = 45;
    }

    public String getKeyPhrase() {
        return keyPhrase;
    }

    public void setKeyPhrase(String keyPhrase) {
        this.keyPhrase = "Ломать и крушить!";
    }



    private String say(){
        return "Меня зовут " + getName() + ", и мне " + getAge();
    }

    private String phrases(){
        return getKeyPhrase();
    }

    private void kick(){ //Суперспособность Удар

    }

    private void laserEyes(){ //Суперспособность Летать

    }

    private void fly(){ //Суперспособность Полет

    }
}
```

Comment: А что вы будете делать, если вам нужно будет присвоить полю `age` значение `20`? Как ваш `setAge()` с этим справится? Какой бы аргумент вы не задали, этот сеттер все равно присвоит 45. Как и другие ваши сеттеры, которые присваивают конкретные значения. Когда ответите на этот вопрос, сразу станет понятно на счет конструктора.

Comment: А что, если мне не надо в дальнейшем больше присваивать значения полю age? Мне нужно, чтобы оно проинициализировалось раз и не изменилось.

Comment: А тогда зачем вам вообще сеттер для этого поля? Как раз конструктор и инициализирует поля класса. Вы создаете объект, где в параметрах конструктора перечисляете все необходимые значения для полей. И все. Не нужно вызывать никаких сеттеров.

Comment: Хорошо. Тогда я делаю поля файнал и инициализирую там же?  А так же убираю сеттер?

Comment: Ну можно и так, если не хотите устанавливать значения полей во время создания объекта. Но сеттеры однозначно не нужны в этом случае.

Comment: Мне кажется, вам вообще не нужен класс Dad. Вам нужен какой-нибудь класс FamilyMember. И тогда FamilyMember dad = FamilyMember(45, "Big Dad");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = "Big Dad";
    }
```

Зачем вы в параметрах вообще тогда запрашиваете String. Если имя всё равно будет Big Dad.
Если придерживаться данной концепции, будущий ваш коллега будет долго ломать голову, почему при любом setName у всех одно и то же имя!

Так делать ни в коем случае нельзя!
Для подобных случаев вам необходимо указать пустой конструктор где

```
class Dad(){
this.name = "Big Dad";
this.age = 45;
}
```

Comment: человек видимо слабо понимает, что такое сеттер и лля чего он нужен. Было бы неплохо, если бы вы в своем ответе прояснили его назначение, а не только сделали замечание о неправильном использовании

Comment: было бы неплохо!

Comment: Наверно ключевое слово тут должно быть, нужно проинициализировать, а не присвоить...

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен в этом случае конструктор только для того, чтобы вы знали, что если объект создан, то переменные, которые должны быть инициализированы, уже инициализированы. В случае с пустым конструктором, вы не можете быть уверены в том, что они инициализированы. Если не обязательно инициализировать некоторые поля или вам не нравится то, что список параметров слишком длинен, воспользуйтесь паттерном "строитель". Если вам не нравится то, что список параметров слишком длинен - паттерн "замена параметров объектом" также вам поможет.
Если же вам нужно инициализировать константы - язык java даст вам это сделать только в конструкторе(и в блоке инициализации). Что логично